# Find the limit: $\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\sqrt [n] {\frac {\left( 2n\right) !} {n!\,n^{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find :
   $$\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\sqrt [n] {\dfrac {\left( 2n\right) !} {n!n^{n}}}$$

Comment: Hint: take a value of $n$, and write out couple of terms...

Comment: Working on it !

Comment: $$\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\sqrt [n] {\dfrac {\left( 2n\right) !} {n!n^{n}}}$$ turns into $$\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\sqrt[n] {\dfrac {\left( 2n\right) !} {n!}}*\frac {1}{n}$$

Comment: @JacobClaassen How does this help?

Comment: Denote the quantity under root sign as $b_{n} $ and find the limit of $b_{n+1}/b_{n}$ to get the answer as $4/e$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if you hadn't close the question,you'd have been able to add your nice comment as an answer...

Comment: @lhf: no worry. I have given many answers based on that technique. You can see that such typical questions with no context should not be encouraged here. But thanks for the  fact that you liked my approach.

Comment: @lhf : the same question is posted again and based on your request I have given the answer. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2257079/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $$(2n)!=2^n \cdot n! \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \ldots (2n-1)$$

Now pull $2^n$ out of the root, cancel out $n!$ and then use logarithms.

You'll get :

$$A=\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n}} \implies \ln A=\ln2 +\sum_{r=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{2r-1}{n} \right)$$

Can you proceed now *(Using Riemann Integrals)*?

> The answer is $\dfrac{4}{e}$

Comment: Reimann sums you mean ?

Comment: Yes. Riemann Integral

Comment: Would it be $$4e^{-1}$$ then?

Comment: Yes It is the correct answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help !

Comment: @DamilaWhiShadow I’m so glad that I could help.