# Proving modular statements .

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove:

a)   $$\left( n+1\right) ^{n}-1\equiv 0 \pmod{n^2}$$

b)    $$ \left( n+2\right) ^{n+2}-2^{n+2}\left( n+1\right) ^{n+1}\equiv 0\pmod{n^2}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean ;   $\equiv \pmod{n^2}$

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Tried this : Bezout : $$\left( n+1\right) \wedge n=1$$

Comment: @DamilaWhiShadow Add that to your question, else your answer may be closed or put on hold as off-topic like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256817/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrt-n-frac-left-2n-right)

Comment: But this is a humble and remote attempt ,it's not worth being mentioned.

Comment: @DamilaWhiShadow You mean that $(n+1)^n \equiv 1 \; \mathrm{mod}\; n$?

Comment: No it's $$\left( n+1\right) ^{n}\equiv 1\left[ n^{2}\right]$$

Comment: Well if you have that. then what's the problem?  Or rather what's $1$ in $\mathrm {mod}\; n^2$?

Comment: B.T.W. $a \; \mathrm {mod}\; b$ isn't normally written as $a[b]$, but rather written as $[a]_b$. This form is more understandable.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll try to adjust,here we write it like that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to try to use the binomial theorem expansion which can be proved by induction, for more details about that see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem.
At least on part a) you should get: 
$$ \sum_0^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k!)}n^k-1 $$
which should expand to something like:
$$n^n+nn^{(n-1)}+...+n^2+1-1=0\ mod \ n^2$$
Hopefully using the same Binomial expansion theorem you should get something useful for the second part.